# How to remove delimiter column in the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have the following dataset in .csv file

when i read the file i get something like this

```
df = pd.read_csv("xxx.csv",dtype = str ,header = None, encoding='utf-8')
df.head()
0   1   2   3   4   5  6 
63  |   ssd |   23  | 4kj
63  |   ssd |   30  | 4rc
63  |   ssd |   900 | 4rt
63  |   ssd |   100 | Bqa
63  |   ssd |   140 | 8er
63  |   ssd |   10  | 8df
63  |   ssd |   40  | Bfr
```

As in the above dataframe 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. when i read the XXX.csv file i just need the column with the information i don't want the column with the delimiter.

expected output

```
    0    1   2  3
    63  ssd 23  4kj
    63  ssd 30  4rc
    63  ssd 900 4rt
    63  ssd 100 Bqa
    63  ssd 140 8er
    63  ssd 10  8df
    63  ssd 40  Bfr
```

How can i get this while reading XXX.csv file

I don't want to use `df = df.drop('column_name', 1)` as my data will be dynamic.

I want to get rid of delimiter column while reading XXX.csv file.

Comment: what do your csv file looks like? it looks like `sep='|'`, i..e pipe-delimited file. At the same time default `sep=','` and it was used to create columns...

Comment: @buran my file looks like **'sep = '|''**

Comment: Then check @dimz answer. And if there is problem on line 3294 - check your file

Comment: @buran there is no problem with the file already checked that I just want the delimiter columns to be removed while reading .csv file. I already tried his solution it’s not working

Comment: please, copy/paste sample of 5-10 rows of your file. If it is pipe-delimited file, the solution suggetsed by @dimz will work. And the problem you claim in the comments is on SPECIFIC line of the file.

Comment: @buran my data is very confidential it look similar to what I have posted in the question.like you said I already went and checked the line .. it seems to be fine.. I don’t see there are any errors in the .csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you try this. ?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('file.csv', delimiter='|')

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='|')
```

Comment: Yes I tried but no use I get the below error message **"ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 31 fields in line 3294, saw 67"**

Comment: try df.replace('|', ","), then use pd.read_csv('file.csv')

Comment: something with the data, need data cleaning, please check if the delimiter is consistent in all lines.

Comment: Yes delimiter is consistent @dimz

Comment: can you try with few lines of file?

Comment: It worked, I just had to delete the 3294th row as it had some ambiguity